# Incorrect Syntax near the keyword 'OR' in CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, ssms, sql-server-2016

I have a master script that runs and create all stored procedures, but when I run the script I error out at the only two places that use the syntax `CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE`

The code is below:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[P_ReinitializeStorePlans]
    @storeId INT
AS
BEGIN    
    RETURN;
END
GO
```

And the error is as follows, I have another `CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE` later at line 2713 as well with the same error.

[image: SQL Error for CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE]

I have checked my @@VERSION which returns SQL 2016 as well as 130 for the compatibility version. Any idea why this is giving me an error? I am assuming its a compatibility setting or flag for the syntax?

[image: SQL Compatibility Versions for Databases]

Comment: You need 2016 with sp1 - [link for install page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54276)

Comment: I have SP1 already, but installing sp2 did the trick!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe this one comes with SP1 installed, this has a version of

```
13.0.4001.0 KB3182545
```

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3177312/sql-server-2016-build-versions

I suggest you go straight to SP2 you can get it from here https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=869608